# how can i ignore compilation error while running npm test using mocha in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying to run some test cases using mocha on my project but, I am not able to run any test and the project contains some compilation errors.

Do we have some option or flag from which we can ingore or suppress errors and run the test cases

script command:
`"test": "mocha --timeout 10000 -r ts-node/register test/*.ts"`

tsconfig.json

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitUseStrict" : true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny" : false, 
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "noStrictGenericChecks" : true,
        "alwaysStrict" : false,
    },
    "include": [
        "src//**/*"
    ]
}
```

Please help !!!!

Comment: Try `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true`

Comment: not helping .. it is not suppressing compilation errors.

Comment: there is a way to ignore all errors from a specific line using `// @ts-ignore` comments before the target line.

Comment: It is not possible to add //@ts-ignore in whole projects

Answer (score 0):

Configuring `transpileOnly` in my `tsconfig.json`, as well as requiring `ts-node/register` solved the problem for me:

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true
  }
  "compilerOptions": {
    // rest of configuration
  }
}
```

And here is my `package.json` configuration:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha"
  },
  "mocha": {
    "spec": "./spec/**/*.spec.[j|t]s",
    "require": "ts-node/register"
  }
}
```

I am using TypeScript 5.3.3 and Mocha 10.2.0